# Jquery autofill for dynamically created forms

Tags: jquery, forms, autocomplete, dynamically-generated, autofill

Hi Guys I'm Trying to do autocomplete and autofill for dynamically created forms.Here by the reference link I came with static field of auto complete and autofill. But I need to achieve for dynamically created forms(add another/remove.).And here is the reference fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q2kDU/

Here by the above fiddle. The label is autocomplete and the value is autofilled depending on the label's value.Here it is in static forms(Only one form). I need to achieve this in dynamically created forms(Add another/Remove).The auto Complete and autofill must be work on all dynamically added field.
Please Help to solve this.I'm new to Jquery.Thanks In Advance.

html

```
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search" />
<input id="searchval" />
```

js

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
    }
});
$(function() {
    var data = [
        {
        label: "anders",
        value: "1",
        category: ""},
    {
        label: "andreas",
        value: "2",
        category: ""},
    {
        label: "antal",
        value: "3",
        category: ""},
    {
        label: "annhhx10",
        value: "4",
        category: "Products"},
    {
        label: "annk K12",
        value: "5",
        category: "Products"},
    {
        label: "annttop C13",
        value: "6",
        category: "Products"},
    {
        label: "anders andersson",
        value: "7",
        category: "People"},
    {
        label: "andreas andersson",
        value: "8",
        category: "People"},
    {
        label: "andreas johnson",
        value: "9",
        category: "People"}
    ];

    $("#search").catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: data,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#search').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#searchval').val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your code for adding or removing new form?

Comment: Ya Im trying that only . I'm new to javascript and jquery.I'm feeling tough to understand this.Can you please help me here.It will be very greatfull for me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As you are explaining you gonna do that for multiple forms hence I recommend you do use classes instead of id.

```
<input id="search" class="searchAuto" />
 $(".searchAuto").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#search').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#searchval').val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please fix it in the fiddle.I'm new to javascript and jquery.I'm feeling tough to understand this. Please fix this in the fiddle. Thank you so much @Parasmani Batra